# When does a function equal its Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm doing the following problem, which is about the condition under which a function equals its Taylor series.

> **Taylor's Inequality.** If $\left|f^{(N+1)}(x)\right| \leq B$ for all $x$ in the interval $[c-d, c+d]$, then the remainder $R_N(x)$ (for the Taylor polynomial to $f(x)$ at $x=c$ ) satisfies the inequality
> $$
> \left|R_N(x)\right| \leq \frac{B}{(N+1) !}|x-c|^{N+1} \quad \text { for all } x \text { in }[c-d, c+d] \text {. }
> $$
> If the right-hand side of Taylor's inequality goes to 0 as $N \rightarrow \infty$, then the remainder must go to 0 as well, and hence for those $x$ values, the function matches its Taylor series.
>
> **Question:** Use Taylor's inequality to show that $e^x$ converges to its Taylor series at $0$ for all real $x$.

I've managed to show what was asked, and checked my answer against the solution. However, I don't understand why we only care about the Taylor series at $0$. I was thinking that we need to show convergence holds for all $c$.

Comment: You’re misinterpreting. We take the Taylor series expanded about $x=a$ (here $a=0$) and ask for values of $x$ the function agrees with the series. It is a confusing answer. Take $c=0$ and show that the result holds for all $d>0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh god, I skimmed through the post and wrote a long answer, then realised that as you said, OP misinterpreted the original question wrong :(

Comment: My concern is that the case $c = 0$ is just one of the many we have to consider, if our goal is to show that convergence always holds.

Comment: Yes, but you show it converges on $[-d,d]$ for all $d>0$. There are better ways of explaining this with fewer symbols.

Comment: Yes I've also just realized we have the radius of convergence equals infinity for this particular function $e^x$, so just considering $c = 0$ is enough. But say for a different function, at some arbitrary $c$, we find out that the radius of convergence happens to be finite. If so, should we investigate other values $c$ as well?